# Mock Component used in MatDialog

Tags: angular, mocking, msal-angular, mat-dialog, angular-jest

I have two libraries/modules with one component Each.
One Component (`MainComponent`) uses the other (`DialogComponent`) in a `MatDialog` open Statement.

The `DialogComponent` uses a Service (`PermissionsServie`) that uses `MsalModule`.

When i mock and provide the `PermissionsServie` in the `MainComponent` unit test thou, the Test fails, stating that it can not create the MsalModule because it is missing the crypto object.

My Test Setup for `MainComponent`:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MainComponent } from './main.component';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { instance, mock } from 'ts-mockito';
import { PermissionsService } from '@my-project/permissions';

describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: MainComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MainComponent>;
  let mockMatDialog: MatDialog;
  let mockPermissionsService: PermissionsService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    mockMatDialog = mock(MatDialog);
    mockPermissionsService = mock(PermissionsService);
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MainComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MatDialog,
          useValue: instance(mockMatDialog),
        },
        {
          provide: PermissionsService,
          useValue: instance(mockPermissionsService),
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

I tried to use `MockComponent(DialogComponent)` as well, but this error stays and i can not run the test.

```
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComponent, MockComponent(TestDialogComponent)],
```

I also tried using `ng-mocks` and `MockBuilder`, mocking the whole module and in a second attempt, mocking the Dialog Module as well, but it doesn't change anything either.